# Order of global filters in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action-filter

I have two global exception filters in Startup

```
config.Filters.AddService(typeof(ExceptionFilter));
```

and

```
config.Filters.AddService(typeof(JsonExceptionFilter));
```

I was always under impression that if the same filter is added first it is executed first.

But when I've added `ExceptionFilter` first it is executed second.

**UPDATE 1**

`ConfigureServices` method:

```
services
    .AddMvc(
         config =>
         {
            config.Filters.AddService(typeof(ExceptionFilter));
            config.Filters.AddService(typeof(JsonExceptionFilter));
         });
```

Comment: what do the `ExceptionFilter` and `JsonExceptionFilter` look like?

Comment: Simple exception handler , one with logging secod with handling request for ajax errors

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order you're registering them in, to see if they're executed in the reverse order?  Maybe they're executed in a LIFO order.

Comment: Yes, when I change the registration order, the order of execution also change.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show more of your startup - I can't make out where `config` is coming from

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With MVC, you can specify an order value that determines the order of execution for your filters.  I don't know if the same applies to ASP.NET Core, and I don't have an IDE in front of me to check.  Would you mind trying this?

```
config.Filters.AddService(typeof(ExceptionFilter), 2);
config.Filters.AddService(typeof(JsonExceptionFilter), 1);
```

Even if that isn't it, check to see if there is another overload of `AddService` that does accept a parameter to specify the order.

Comment: Ok there is additional option. So this will solve the issue. However I'm supprised the order is not predetermined by order of adding

Comment: @Marcin There's a bit more information about order of execution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters), but it talks more about the order of action filters, as opposed to how multiple exception filters would work together.  My guess, as I mentioned above, is they're executed as a stack using LIFO order.